# Sql script when run vi mysql python gives error

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I wrote a python script to execute my sql script. When i manually run this sql script using source it doesn't give me any error just warning and it fully executes as :

```
mysql> source the_actual_script.sql
Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.29 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

But when i try and run it via my python code :

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("aws.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com","prod_user","pass","db_name")
cursor = db.cursor()
for line in open("/home/ubuntu/PATCHER/the_check_query.sql"):
  print  cursor.execute(line)
db.close()
```

It gives me errors :

```
test.py:8: Warning: PROCEDURE saas_neopostsa.temp_prod does not exist
  cursor.execute(line)
test.py:8: Warning: PROCEDURE saas_neopostsa.temp_prod_neopost does not exist
  cursor.execute(line)
test.py:8: Warning: PROCEDURE saas_neopostsa.temp_prod_neopostsa does not exist
  cursor.execute(line)
test.py:8: Warning: Unknown table 'temp_identity_neopostsa'
  cursor.execute(line)
test.py:8: Warning: Unknown table 'temp_identity'
  cursor.execute(line)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    cursor.execute(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1065, 'Query was empty')
```

can someone help me what's wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading external sql script in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472922/reading-external-sql-script-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL ER_EMPTY_QUERY or Empty Query error indicates the query being executed is either empty or a value which MySQL cannot convert to a string.  I'd review the script file and be sure each line has an SQL statement.

```
for line in open("/home/ubuntu/PATCHER/the_check_query.sql"):
  print  cursor.execute(line)
db.close()
```

You should consider the `with` keyword for your file operations (assuming your version supports this keyword).  I'd probably perform this with some sort of validation, something like:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("aws.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com","prod_user","pass","db_name")
cursor = db.cursor()

# Use with to open the file,'rb' for compatibility
with open("/home/ubuntu/PATCHER/the_check_query.sql",'rb') as infile:
    # Using list comprehension, read lines ecluding non-empty
    # or lines containing only a newline ('\n') character
    lines = [ln for ln in infile.readlines() if ln and ln != '\n']

# The file is now closed and you have a (somewhat) curated command list
for line in lines:
    try:
        cursor.execute(line)
    except:
        print line  # see what exactly is being executed
        # Other exception stuff here

db.close()
```

This will, at least, provide you with a clear picture of which command is resulting in the Empty Query error.

Is there an empty line or doubled semicolon (;;) anywhere in the script file after the 5th test?  I'm a little confused since the stack trace is showing `cursor.execute(line)` and not `print cursor.execute(line)` as in your code sample and doesn't match the line number for the sample.  Is the code provided the full relevant section of code which actually generated that stack trace?

Comment: It says mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$' at line 1")