# SQL file executes in MySQL workbench but not in python

Tags: python, mysql, data-migration

I'm writing a python script to migrate data from one MySQL database to another. The script loads a sql file dumped by mysqldump and splits the commands similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472922/reading-external-sql-script-in-python) SO question. When I execute the script in python 2.7 using the python-mysql library, python outputs the following error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'\\"><script>alert(1)\' at line 1')
```

Checking the associated file, I see that python fails when it tries to execute a massive insert statement that includes 6 records like this:

```
('58cd48g5158b8','2015-12-02 16:05:25','\"><script>alert(1);</script>','12.16.98.253')
```

But, if I were to execute the same file in MySQL Workbench, it completes without an error.

## 1. Why does MySQL server execute the file without problems, but mysql-python errors out?

## 2. Why does python treat the string as a a SQL syntax error?

Note: this table is the 13th to be processed in the script and the insert command is the 18th command for that table; so, I doubt it's an issue with my code.

#### Relevant Python Code

```
def loadMigrationScriptForTable(self, tableName, schemaName='obfuscated'):
    fileName = 'obfuscated' + schemaName + '.' + tableName + '.sql'
    fileDir = self.conf.get('obfuscated', 'obfuscated')
    workfile = os.path.join(fileDir, fileName)
    try:
        file = open(workfile, 'r')
        contents = file.read()
        return contents
    except IOError:
        return Exception('File does not exist: '+workfile)

# Migrate tables whose table definition has not been altered but row counts has changed.
def migrateTablesWithUnmodifiedDefinition(self):
    tables = self.conf.get('obfuscated', 'obfuscated').split(', ')
    responses = []
    for table in tables:
        # Load SQL file (as string)
        MySQLScript = self.loadMigrationScriptForTable(table)
        if(isinstance(MySQLScript, Exception)):
            print table, MySQLScript
            continue # Skip remaining code if file couldn't load.

        # Split commands
        sqlCommands = MySQLScript.split(';')
        for sqlCommand in sqlCommands:
            # Execute SQL file.
            print table, sqlCommand[0:99]
            response = self.db.executeScript(sqlCommand)
            print "        ", response
            responses.append(response)

def executeScript(self, script):
    self._DB.connection.execute(script)
```

Comment: I'm sure it *is* an issue with your code, but since you haven't posted any we can't say one way or the other.

Comment: Updated w/ relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

As `Daniel Roseman` hinted, *it was an issue with my code*. When parsing and splitting sql files generated by mysqldump you should split it based on the semicolon **and newline character**, otherwise `string.split` will split on semicolons inside strings.

#### Erroneous Code

```py
# Split commands
sqlCommands = MySQLScript.split(';')
```

#### Fixed Code

```py
# Split commands
sqlCommands = MySQLScript.split(';\n')
```

#### OS  Note

Note: This works on windows; but, I have not tested it yet on *nix yet. If running on *nix, it may be more prudent to use [string.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).

```
# Split commands
sqlCommands = MySQLScript.splitlines()
```

Comment: I added the OS note in case `\n` makes a difference with respect to `CR LF` line terminators.