# Handle GO in pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I wrote a Python script that uses `pyodbc` (via SQLAlchemy) to execute T-SQL files. Some files are littered with `GO` statements:

```sql
-- query.sql
USE db_name
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE OR ALTER VIEW ...
```

How I execute the file:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

with open("query.sql") as fp:
    query = text(fp.read())

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://...")
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(query)
```

I cannot automatically remove the `GO` lines from my script since `CREATE OR ALTER VIEW` must be the first statement in a batch. How should I execute these files?

Comment: `go` is not part of TSQL per se, it's just a batch terminator. It says "when you see me, send what you've read so far to the server for it to execute". So that's what you should do, too. You can't just read the whole file and send it to the server as "one query". You read the file line by line into a buffer until you see a "go", then send the buffer to be executed, clear it, and repeat until you reach the end of the file.

Comment: Agree with above speaker. It gets funny if you have strings or comments spanning multiple lines containing GOs.

Comment: Imperfect, but check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472922/reading-external-sql-script-in-python

Comment: By the way, the first line in your script doesn't need to be `go` for your create/alter to work. `go` is just a safe way in ssms/sqlcmd, etc. to be _sure_ the previous statement is done. If the first line of your script/batch is create/alter, you're good to go (unless you're concatenating scripts together)